# Python: sorting the values of a dict and extracting the keys corresponding to the last n values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Say you have a dict like this, but not necessarily ordered in its values:

`d={a:2,k:2,c:11,f:17,e:84,y:86}`

And you want to sort the values largest to smallest:

`order=sorted(d.values(),reverse=True)`

This will give you:

`order=[86,84,17,11,2,2]`

Now, let's take the last two elements:

`b=order[-2:]=[2,2]`

**What is a Pythonic way of retrieving the keys in `d` to which the values in `b` correspond?** In this case, the intended outcome would be:

`ans=[a,k]`

Comment: A dict is never ordered (regarding your first sentence)

Comment: Yes, I know that. I've specified that because my example is ordered in the values.

Comment: Could you make this a full answer?

Comment: _What is a Pythonic way of retrieving the keys in d to which the values in b correspond?_ There is no pythonic way or any other way to do this since the same values might be "shared" by many keys. Getting the last two elements after the sorting is a different thing..

Comment: @CF84 I answered to show you how tu use `np.argsort`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `key` argument to [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted) to get a list of keys sorted by values:

```
>>> d = {'a': 2, 'k': 2, 'c': 11, 'f': 17, 'e': 84, 'y': 86}
>>> sorted(d, key=d.get)[:2]
['a', 'k']
```

To quote the documentation:

> *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each element in *iterable* (for example,
>   `key=str.lower`). The default value is `None` (compare the elements
>   directly).

Alternatively, (if `n` is small) you can use [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest), which avoids sorting all the keys:

```
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> nsmallest(2, d, key=d.get)
['a', 'k']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is **another** method using `np.argsort` :

```
d.values()
# returns [2, 11, 84, 17, 2, 86]

np.argsort(d.values())
# array([0, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5]). 
# Returns the indices that would sort an array.

# Now use it to retrieve the corresponding keys :
for i in np.argsort(d.values())[:2]:
    print d.keys()[i]
```

**Result**:

```
'a'
'k'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want key and values both after sorting the `dict`, you may do:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> order = sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
>>> order[-2:]
[('a', 2), ('k', 2)]
```